# Matplotlib embedded in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

Investigating how to use tkinter controls with buttons and sliders and to combine these with matplotlib, I have come to the following code. Suggestions for improvements and tips are most welcome. Ultimate goal is to make some apps showing behavior of pendulums, springs and other physical systems where I can interactively change parameters like velocity, angle, weight, length, and so on.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import math
import numpy as np


FIG_SIZE = (8, 6)
PLOT_LIMIT = 12
TICK_INTERVAL = 1.5

def transform_point(point, angle):
        alpha = - angle/180 * math.pi
        x_t = point[0] * math.cos(alpha) - point[1] * math.cos(math.pi/2 - alpha)
        y_t = point[0] * math.sin(alpha) + point[1] * math.sin(math.pi/2 - alpha)
        return x_t, y_t

class MplMap():

    @classmethod
    def settings(cls, root, fig_size, plot_limit):
        # set the plot outline, including axes going through the origin
        cls.fig, cls.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=fig_size)
        cls.plot_limit = plot_limit
        cls.ax.set_xlim(-cls.plot_limit, cls.plot_limit)
        cls.ax.set_ylim(-cls.plot_limit, cls.plot_limit)
        cls.ax.set_aspect(1)
        tick_range = np.arange(
            round(-cls.plot_limit + (10*cls.plot_limit % TICK_INTERVAL*10)/10, 1), 
            cls.plot_limit + 0.1, 
            step=TICK_INTERVAL)
        cls.ax.set_xticks(tick_range)
        cls.ax.set_yticks(tick_range)
        cls.ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=6)
        cls.ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
        cls.ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
        cls.ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
        cls.ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
        cls.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(cls.fig, master=root)

    @classmethod
    def get_canvas(cls):
        return cls.canvas


class PlotRectangle(MplMap):

    def __init__(self):
        self._facecolor = 'none'
        self._edgecolor = 'green'
        self._lw = 5
        self.alpha = 0
        c1 = (-1, +1)
        c2 = (-2, +4)
        c3 = (+2, +4)
        c4 = (+1, +1)
        self.a_shape = np.array([c1, c2, c3, c4])
        self.plot_shape()

    def plot_shape(self):
        self.clear_map()
        trsfd_shape = []
        for point in self.a_shape:
            trsfd_shape.append(transform_point(point, self.alpha))

        trsfd_shape = np.array(trsfd_shape)    
        self.ax.fill(trsfd_shape[:, 0], trsfd_shape[:, 1], 
                     fc=self._facecolor,
                     ec=self._edgecolor,
                     lw=self._lw)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def clear_map(self):
        for patch in self.ax.patches:
            patch.remove()

    def set_color(self, color):
        self._edgecolor = color
        self.plot_shape()

    def set_angle(self, alpha):
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.plot_shape()

    def set_line_width(self, width):
        self._lw = width/10
        self.plot_shape()


class Tk_Handler():

    def __init__(self, root, canvas, shape):
        self.root = root
        self.shape = shape

        self.root.wm_title("Embedding MPL in tkinter")
        sliders_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        slider_frame_1 = tk.Frame(sliders_frame)
        label_slider_1 = tk.Label(slider_frame_1, text='\nAngle: ')
        slider_1 = tk.Scale(slider_frame_1, from_=-180, to=180, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                            command=lambda angle: self._tilt_shape(angle))
        slider_1.set(0)
        label_slider_1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        slider_1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        slider_frame_1.pack()

        slider_frame_2 = tk.Frame(sliders_frame)
        label_slider_2 = tk.Label(slider_frame_2, text='\nWidth: ')
        slider_2 = tk.Scale(slider_frame_2, from_=0, to=10, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                            command=lambda width: self._lw_shape(width))
        slider_2.set(5)
        label_slider_2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        slider_2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        slider_frame_2.pack()

        button_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        quit_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Quit", command=self._quit)\
            .pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        green_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Green",\
            command=lambda *args: self._color_shape('green', *args))\
            .pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        red_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Red",\
            command=lambda *args: self._color_shape('red', *args))\
            .pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        # fill the grid
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self.root, 0, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self.root, 0, weight=1)
        sliders_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NW)
        button_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=1, columnspan=1,
                                    sticky=tk.W+tk.E+tk.N+tk.S)

        tk.mainloop()

    def _quit(self):
        self.root.quit()     # stops mainloop
        self.root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
                             # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate

    def _color_shape(self, color):
        self.shape.set_color(color)

    def _lw_shape(self, width):
        self.shape.set_line_width(float(width)*4)

    def _tilt_shape(self, angle):
        self.shape.set_angle(float(angle))


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    MplMap.settings(root, FIG_SIZE, PLOT_LIMIT)
    Tk_Handler(root, MplMap.get_canvas(), PlotRectangle())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```